# How to fetch multiple duplicate value count in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have database in which user device id and device registerd date (cr_date) stored i want to fetch list of total count of registerd devices on same day with date wise

Here below display table structure

```
device_ID   | cr_date 
--------------------
    1       | 2016-06-02 18:02:13   
    2       | 2016-06-02 18:03:58
    3       | 2016-06-02 18:04:11
    4       | 2016-06-03 18:04:33
    5       | 2016-06-03 18:04:33
    6       | 2016-06-04 18:04:44
```

and i want below result

```
count   |  date 
---------------------------------
    3   |   2016-06-02
    2   |   2016-06-03
    1   |   2016-06-04
```

i used below query but dosent get success

```
SELECT device_type, count(*) AS duplicate_count
FROM (
 SELECT device_type FROM tbl_app_deviceregister
 GROUP BY device_type HAVING COUNT(device_type) > 0
) AS t
```

Comment: The table's and the query's columns don't match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want this;)

```
SELECT count(1) as `count`, date_format(cr_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as `date`
FROM tbl_app_deviceregister
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks men, yes this is that i want. you save my day

Answer (score 0):

You should `GROUP BY` date value, not by device:

```sql
SELECT CAST(cr_date AS DATE) AS `date`, COUNT(device_id) 
FROM tbl_app_deviceregister
GROUP BY CAST(cr_date AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't seem to reference the same table structure that you've described, but from what I understand, would this work?

```
SELECT count(id), date_registered FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(cr_date)) as date_registered 
    FROM 
        tbl_app_deviceregister
) A GROUP BY date_registered
```

Answer (score 0):

you group it by device_type which is wrong. try to group by date.

```
select COUNT(*) as count,CONVERT(date,cr_date) as date
from tbl_app_deviceregister
group by CONVERT(date,cr_date)
```